# Delete the last instance of a letter in string

Tags: ruby, string

How do I delete only the last `"l"` from a string and not the others?

```
string = "Hello"
```

desired outcome:

```
string # => "Helo"
```

I did:

```
string.delete!("l")
string #= > "Heo"
```

Comment: For `"lol"`, do you want `"lo"`, or `"ol"`?

Comment: thanks everyone for all the responses. truly helpful! @sawa - it would be "lo" since the last "l" would need to be deleted

Comment: Your example was bad. You should have used an example like `"lol"` instead of `"Hello"` to make your point clearer.

Comment: @sawa thanks for the down vote. appreciate it. maybe the line in the question: "delete only the last "l" from a string" wasn't clear enough

Comment: @user3007294 Yes. Writing like that and posting an example for which it does not matter which `"l"` is deleted made it confusing. I hope you learn from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[string.rindex('l')] = ''
```

Comment: this matches the first occurence, not the last

Comment: @boulder_ruby, no it doesn't. That is why it is `rindex` and not `index`.

Comment: I just plugged this solution into my code and the output worked correctly. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to replace a single occurrence and tweak the regexp to replace the last match.

```
string = "Homemade"
string.sub(/(.*)m/, '\1')
# => "Homeade"
```

In your case the regexp will be

```
string.sub(/(.*)l/, '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'hello'

r = /
    .*  # match any number of any character
    \K  # discard everything matched so far
    l   # match last 'l'
   /x   # extended mode

str.gsub(r,'')
  #=> "helo"
```